# SQLite select, join and where clause problems

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Im trying to populate a listview with data from 3 tables using join, and one table to check wether a user is part of a group. But im having trouble getting all the groups for a given user. Heres the tables
Group table

```
_id | group_name | group_description | group_image
```

User table

```
_id | user_name | user_image
```

Group participants table (this table determines which users are part of which groups)

```
_id | user_id_foreign | group_id_foreign
```

Activityobject table

```
_id | target_id | user_id_foreign | target_type | time | type
```

Here is the sql statement im trying to get to work:

```
Cursor c = database
            .rawQuery(
                    "SELECT groups.*, activityobject.time, activityobject.type, user.user_name, user.user_image "
                            + "FROM activityobject "
                            + "JOIN user "
                            + "ON user._id = activityobject.user_id "
                            + "JOIN groups"
                            + "ON groups._id = activityobject.target_id "
                            + "WHERE groups._id IN(SELECT group_id_foreign FROM group_participants WHERE user_id_foreign = ?)"
                            + "AND activityobject.target_type = 0 "
                            + "GROUP BY groups._id "
                            + "ORDER BY activityobject._id",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(userId) });
```

The result i get right now are all the groups that has an activityobject, but not the ones without. 
I would like to get all groups for a given user, and if a group has an activityobject i want data from that object aswell.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
An image of the tables im refering to
[image]
Heres my insert statements with data in the tables

```
//Activity object table
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACTIVITYOBJECT + " ("
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ACTIVITY_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_USER_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_NAME + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TIME + ", " + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_OBJECT_ID
            + ") VALUES (1, 2, 1, 1, 'Alex gruppe', 0, '07-05-13', 1)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACTIVITYOBJECT + " ("
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ACTIVITY_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_USER_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_NAME + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TIME + ", " + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_OBJECT_ID
            + ") VALUES (2, 2, 1, 2, 'Jeremys gruppe', 0, '08-06-13', 2)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACTIVITYOBJECT + " ("
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ACTIVITY_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_USER_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_NAME + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TIME + ", " + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_OBJECT_ID
            + ") VALUES (3, 2, 1, 2, 'Jeremys gruppe', 1, '09-07-13',3)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACTIVITYOBJECT + " ("
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ACTIVITY_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_USER_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_NAME + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TIME + ", " + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_OBJECT_ID
            + ") VALUES (4, 2, 1, 2, 'Jeremys gruppe', 0, '10-08-13', 4)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACTIVITYOBJECT + " ("
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ACTIVITY_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_USER_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_NAME + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TIME + ", " + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_OBJECT_ID
            + ") VALUES (5, 2, 1, 1, 'Alex gruppe', 0, '11-09-13', 5)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACTIVITYOBJECT + " ("
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ACTIVITY_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_USER_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_NAME + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TIME + ", " + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_OBJECT_ID
            + ") VALUES (6, 2, 1, 1, 'Alex gruppe', 0, '12-10-13', 6)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACTIVITYOBJECT + " ("
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ACTIVITY_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_USER_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_NAME + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TIME + ", " + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_OBJECT_ID
            + ") VALUES (7, 2, 1, 1, 'Alex gruppe', 1, '13-11-13', 7)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACTIVITYOBJECT + " ("
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_ACTIVITY_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_USER_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_ID + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_NAME + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TARGET_TYPE + ", "
            + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_TIME + ", " + KEY_ACTIVITYOBJECT_OBJECT_ID
            + ") VALUES (8, 2, 1, 1, 'Alex gruppe', 0, '14-12-13', 8)");
    // Group table
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_GROUP + " ( " + KEY_GROUP_ID + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_NAME + ", " + KEY_GROUP_INFO + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_IMAGE
            + ") VALUES (1,'alex gruppe', 'mega awesome gruppe', null);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_GROUP + " ( " + KEY_GROUP_ID + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_NAME + ", " + KEY_GROUP_INFO + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_IMAGE
            + ") VALUES (2,'jeremy gruppe', 'mega awesome gruppe', null);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_GROUP + " ( " + KEY_GROUP_ID + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_NAME + ", " + KEY_GROUP_INFO + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_IMAGE
            + ") VALUES (3,'ole gruppe', 'mega awesome gruppe', null);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_GROUP + " ( " + KEY_GROUP_ID + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_NAME + ", " + KEY_GROUP_INFO + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_IMAGE
            + ") VALUES (4,'egon gruppe', 'mega awesome gruppe', null);");
    // User table
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_USER + " (" + KEY_USER_ID + ", "
            + KEY_USER_NAME + ", " + KEY_USER_IMAGE + ", "
            + KEY_USER_STATUS + ") VALUES (1, 'Alex', null, 0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_USER + " (" + KEY_USER_ID + ", "
            + KEY_USER_NAME + ", " + KEY_USER_IMAGE + ", "
            + KEY_USER_STATUS + ") VALUES (2, 'Peter', null, 0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_USER + " (" + KEY_USER_ID + ", "
            + KEY_USER_NAME + ", " + KEY_USER_IMAGE + ", "
            + KEY_USER_STATUS + ") VALUES (3, 'Jeremy', null, 0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_USER + " (" + KEY_USER_ID + ", "
            + KEY_USER_NAME + ", " + KEY_USER_IMAGE + ", "
            + KEY_USER_STATUS + ") VALUES (4, 'Søren', null, 0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_USER + " (" + KEY_USER_ID + ", "
            + KEY_USER_NAME + ", " + KEY_USER_IMAGE + ", "
            + KEY_USER_STATUS + ") VALUES (5, 'Ole', null, 0)");

    // Group participants table
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_GROUP_PARTICIPANTS + " ( "
            + KEY_GROUP_PARTICIPANTS_ID + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_PARTICIPANTS_USER_ID_FOREIGN + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_PARTICIPANTS_GROUP_ID_FOREIGN + ") VALUES(1, 1, 1)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_GROUP_PARTICIPANTS + " ( "
            + KEY_GROUP_PARTICIPANTS_ID + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_PARTICIPANTS_USER_ID_FOREIGN + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_PARTICIPANTS_GROUP_ID_FOREIGN + ") VALUES(2, 1, 4)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_GROUP_PARTICIPANTS + " ( "
            + KEY_GROUP_PARTICIPANTS_ID + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_PARTICIPANTS_USER_ID_FOREIGN + ", "
            + KEY_GROUP_PARTICIPANTS_GROUP_ID_FOREIGN + ") VALUES(3, 2, 2)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I would like to get all groups for a given user, and if a group has an activityobject i want data from that object aswell."

You have to use a LEFT JOIN then.

```
select g.*, a.time, a.type, u.user_name, u.user_image                             
from groups g
    join group_participants gp on gp.group_id_foreign = g._id
    left join activityobject a on g._id = a.target_id and a.target_type = 0
    left join user u on a.user_id_foreign = u.id
where gp.user_id_foreign = ?
order by a._id;
```

If you just want to select the last activity object per group (if any), you can add that to the join condition, too:

```
select g.*, a.*
from groups g
    join group_participants gp on gp.group_id_foreign = g._id
    left join activityobject a 
        on g._id = a.target_id and 
           a.target_type = 0 and 
           a._id in (select max(_id) from activityobject group by target_id)  
    left join users u on a.user_id_foreign = u.id
where gp.user_id_foreign = ?
order by a._id;
```

Just keep in mind that you have to add all filtering criteria for activityobjects to the join condition of the left join, not to the where clause of your main query. Otherwise, you will surpress rows from the result where no matching activityobject can be found, instead of filling up the columns with nulls.

Comment: I have updated the sql. Does this seem more right? I just tried selecting activityobject and join the rest of the tables to this table. But it doesnt make any difference in the result set. I still only get the groups that has an activityobject

Comment: I think you should join groups, users, and participants (inner join), plus a left join on activities, and the where condition to restrict to the ones you want to show. I will update the query in a second.

Comment: Is this now doing what you want?

Comment: Hmm strange, i still end up with the same result as before. It returns one row but it should return two. It still seems like it neglects the group that doesnt apper in the activityobject table. Any thoughts? EDIT: Is there a reason you left out the ORDER BY clause? if i leave it out i get all the activityobjects from the group and not just one (i only want one result from activityobject)

Comment: Could you post some sample data?

Comment: Before or after the where clause?

Comment: You meant the GROUP BY clause? If there are multiple activityobjects associated with one group, Which activity object do you want to get then?

Comment: If you want to join only on the activityobjects with target_type = 0, you need to add that to the join condition of the left join (i have edited the query in my answer)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41263/discussion-between-fabian-and-alex-m-k)

Comment: Yea sure just give me a sec. Editing the main post

Comment: By the way: You might want to double-check that you use the right columns in your join conditions: You have a column user_id_foreign in table activityobject, which you do not use - is that intended?

Comment: I dont think I was clear enough in my question. The user i want to select is the user who created the activityobject, hence the user_id_foreign you asked about in activityobject table. The u._id in the where clause is the user who logged in the app, so this is not the same user as the one im trying to select. So is there a way where i can get u.* only if the group has an activityobject? and still keep the u._id in the where clause.

Comment: I added a picture of the database model

Comment: I have changed the query, let me see if I got you right this time. Now it selects all groups of a given user id  (where gp.user_id_foreign = ?) and selects the activity object for that group with the max id (given that is has type = 0) if that exists. If there is user connected to that activity object (by a.user_id_foreign), that is selected, too. Otherwise, everything is filled with nulls. Is that what you need?